# SVG <rect> not animating or transitioning smoothly/at all

Tags: html, css, svg

I have something like this in my html document:

```
<svg _ngcontent-ng-c2089998032="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="bottom-app-bar__hole2" style="z-index: 10;">
  <mask _ngcontent-ng-c2089998032="" id="circular-hole2">
    <rect _ngcontent-ng-c2089998032="" height="100%" fill="white" width="100%"></rect>
    <rect _ngcontent-ng-c2089998032="" id="rectHole2" fill="black" x="0" rx="54" y="-34" height="70" width="108"></rect>
  </mask>
  <rect _ngcontent-ng-c2089998032="" height="100%" mask="url(#circular-hole2)" x="0" width="100%">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

And this in css:

```
.bottom-app-bar__middle svg.bottom-app-bar__hole2 mask #rectHole2 {
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: center; 
    animation: scaleFlat;
    animation-duration: 4.400s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.7, 0.1, 1.0);
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  }
  .bottom-app-bar__middle.hover svg.bottom-app-bar__hole2 mask #rectHole2 {
    animation: scaleFlat;
    animation-duration: 4.400s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.7, 0.1, 1.0);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  }
```

But my  is changing in one step without transition.

I assuming that I did something wrong but have no idea what?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the `@keyframes` rule.